# Prove that $u(x,t)\leq v(x,t)$ in $U_T$ (Heat equation)

Tags: partial-differential-equations

> Let $U \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be open, bounded, and connected. Let $T>0$ be a given terminal time and $\Gamma_T$ denote the parabolic boundary of $U_T$. Suppose that $u,v \in C^{2}_1 (U_T)\cap C (\overline{U}_T)$ are solutions of the initial-boundary-value problems
>   $$
> \begin{aligned}
> u_{t}(x,t) - \Delta u(x,t) &= f_1(x,t)\quad\text{in}~U_T\\
> u(x,t) &= f_2(x,t) \quad\text{on}~\Gamma_T
> \end{aligned}
> $$ 
>   and
>   $$
> \begin{aligned}
> v_{t}(x,t) - \Delta v(x,t) &= g_1(x,t)\quad\text{in}~U_T\\
> v(x,t) &= g_2(x,t) \quad\text{on}~\Gamma_T
> \end{aligned}
> $$
>   where $f_1(x,t)\leq g_1(x,t)$ in $U_T$ and $f_2(x,t)\leq g_2(x,t)$ on $\Gamma_T$. Prove that $u(x,t)\leq v(x,t)$ in $U_T$.

I am trying to prove this using energy methods. For example if I can say that $I(t)=\int u(x,t)-v(x,t)\leq0$ then we have the answer.
So when I'm differentiating $I(t)$ with respect to $t$ and using Green's identity, I get stuck in a normal vector perpendicular to the boundary.
Am I doing something wrong or is there any other way to get in to the solution.
Appreciate your help